# symfony2: exception when trying to display localized country name - Only the locale "en" is supported."

Tags: symfony, internationalization

I'd like to display the full name of a country in french but I get this error:
**An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Only the locale "en" is supported.") in FOSUserBundle:Profile:show_content.html.twig at line 48.**

this the code :

**service.yml**

```
    boutique.twig.country_extension:
    class: Boutique\UserBundle\Twig\CountryExtension
    tags:
        - { name: twig.extension }
```

**CountryExtension.php**

```
<?php
// src/Boutique/UserBundle/Twig/CountryExtension.php
namespace Boutique\UserBundle\Twig;


class CountryExtension extends \Twig_Extension {
    public function getFilters()
    {
        return array(
            new \Twig_SimpleFilter('country', array($this, 'countryFilter')),
        );
    }

    public function countryFilter($countryCode,$locale = "en"){
        $c = \Symfony\Component\Locale\Locale::getDisplayCountries($locale);

        return array_key_exists($countryCode, $c)
            ? $c[$countryCode]
            : $countryCode;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'country_extension';
    }
}
```

**twig**

```
{{ user.country|country(app.request.locale) }}
```

**parameters.yml**

```
# This file is auto-generated during the composer install
parameters:
database_driver: pdo_mysql
database_host: 127.0.0.1
//.............
locale: fr
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to install PHP's Internationalization extension `php5-intl`.

Quote from documentation:

> The replacement layer is limited to the locale "en". If you want to
>   use other locales, you should install the intl extension instead.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/intl.html

Answer (score 0):

your function

```
public function countryFilter($countryCode,$locale = "en"){
```

expects two arguments, countryCode and local which by default is "en" if not provided

in your filter call you are just passing one argument

```
user.country|country(app.request.locale)
```

so $locale is not provided and will be the default value "en"

or am i missing sth. ?

Answer (score 0):

In your app/config/config.yml, those lines are not commented ?

translator:      { fallback: "%locale%" }
default_locale:  "%locale%"

@john Smith:

With this filter, you get all the arguments

"user.country" pass in $countryCode and "app.request.locale" in $locale

Comment: Yes they are not commented